# Clicking the "flag" action link on a notified-as-edited question results in wrong internal page state

Tags: bug, edits, questions, flags

When trying to flag a post (question, in this case; I haven't tried with answers, but I suspect that it works much the same so may have the same problem) which is being edited, it seems like the page internal state can end up being inconsistent, leading to an incorrect error message displayed to the user.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the page for a question, any question, any question at all.
2. Open the same question in an additional tab, or coordinate with an additional user to do so.
3. In the second tab, make an edit to the question.
4. In the first tab, note that the "an edit has been made" bar appears at the top. *Do not dismiss this.*
5. In the first tab, click the "flag" action link below the question text. **Expected result:** Flag dialog should open. **Observed behavior:** The question text is refreshed with the edit, but the flag dialog does not open.
6. In the first tab, immediately click the "flag" action link again. **Observed behavior:** An error message appears that you can only open the flag dialog once every three seconds.

**The workaround** is easy: just wait those few seconds and try again.

**I'm suggesting** that instead of as observed in step 5 above, the text should be refreshed and a message should be displayed to the user encouraging them to reconsider the flag in light of the edit now visible, but that this does not count as actually opening the flag dialog.

Comment: dupe. just a second

Comment: @OptimusPrime I'm not sure whether or not that's a duplicate. Mind you, that's asking about the close dialog, and this is about the flag dialog. *Might* be the same underlying issue which would be fixed by making the exact same change, or might not.

Comment: both are same and the root cause is same. If an edit is made, clicking any action will refresh the post. If you clicked on close/flag, then it will register the click and refresh the post. so you can't open it for the next 3 seconds

Comment: Maybe turn the dupes around. This one has a more clear problem statement and repro steps but they are both the same issue.